# Is the MySQL USER the same as the createPool user?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is the `user` specified in `createPool()` the same as the one in mentioned in the error message I am getting?

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DBNAME
})
```

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sql: undefined
```

My database is currently hosted on AWS, but I want to do some testing locally. Should the parameters in `createPool()` be switched to localhost then?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is yes. If anyone else happens to have the same silly question as me, there's a possibility that your environment variables are not being read properly.

Make sure to first `npm install dotenv` and then within your Node.js code, include `require('dotenv').config()` on the top of your file.